# Calculating a map point which forms a triangle

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

If I have point A and B on a map, how can I calculate the latitude and longitude of a point C which would form an equilateral triangle as you look at the map, for any given points A and B?

I'm programming Android/Java but this is more about the maths required.

Comment: This may belong here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: calculate the distance between A and B, then find the point that is that distance away from both A and B (hint: there will be 2 of them)

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. Latitude and longitude gets skewed depending on the bearing of point A to B, so when you plot that point on the map it can be sort of anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the distance and the bearing from A to B. Then add (or subtract) 60 degrees to the bearing. Starting from A, Point C has this bearing and the same distance.

You may use e.g. the [SphericalUtil](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/) to do all the calculations:

Then it's:

```
dist = computeDistance(A,B);
heading = computeHeading(A,B);
C = computeOffset(A,dist,heading+60);
```